# How can $f(x)=x^4$ have a global minimum at $x=0$ but $f''(0)=0$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$f(x)=x^4$ has a global minimum in $\Bbb R$ at the point $x=0$, but $f''(0)=0$.

This case confuses me. For every $0\neq x\in I$, $f(x)>f(0)$. So how can it be that $f''(0)=0$, following $f'(x)$ doesn't change its sign at $x=0$?
I could accept it if there was a little segment $I$ around $x=0$ fulfilling $f(x)=0$ for every $x\in I$. But I don't see why that can be the case, since, again, $x=0$ is the only $x$ fulfilling $f(x)=0$.

This contradicts my logic. Can someone help me understand how this is possible?

Comment: Ah, you've just hit upon a case where the second derivative test fails. :-)

Comment: Why do you think that $f^{"}(0)=0\Rightarrow f'(x)$ doesn't change its sign?

Comment: @EclipseSun because $f''(x)$ shows the difference in $f'(x)$ at the same point, but 0 difference means no change in $f'(x)$... Or am I wrong?

Comment: It is not "difference", but the "rate of difference". Your example clearly shows that $f'(x)=4x^3$ does change its sign at $x=0$.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no contradiction. For a local minimum (of a sufficiently differentiable function) at $x=a$ it is a *necessary* condition that $f'(a)=0$ and it is *sufficient* that $f'(a)=0$ and $f''(a)>0$. With $f(x)=x^4$ we are in the wide range between the necessary and the sufficient.

For real fun, consider $$f(x)=\begin{cases}e^{-1/x^2}&\text{if }x\ne 0\\0&\text{if }x=0\end{cases} $$
and show that $f$ has a unique local minimum at $x=0$, whereas all derivatives exist and are equal to $0$ at $x=0$.

Comment: How do I show it has a maximum without using the second-derivative test?

Comment: "maximum" should be "minimum" in the answer at hand. How show this function has a minimum at $x=0$? simple: use the *definition* of "minimum"!

Comment: @murray yes, pardon me. I forgot my definitions.
And yes, it should be minimum. For every $0\neq x\in \Bbb R$, $f(x)>f(0)$.

Just to make sure - is it true that for every a>0 and function f(x), $a^{f(x)}>0$?

Comment: @Whyka: Certainly if $a > 0$ and $b > 0$, then $a^b > 0$.

Comment: @murray of course. The point is, b doesn't have to be larger than 0

Comment: @Whyka: right, $a > 0$ implies $a^b > 0$ for all real $b$. In your example, $f(x) > 0$ for all $x \neq 0$ and $f{0} = 0$, which is why I gave the condition $b > 0$.

Answer (score 5):

$f'(x)$ does change it sign at $0$ though. Calculate $f'(x)$ and try point either side of $0$ and you will see this.